# How can I create an unencrypted PKCS#12 certificate?

Tags: ssl, openssl

Given a certificate, `thing.crt` and a key, `thing.key`, I can create an PKCS#12 certificate with:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in thing.crt -inkey thing.key -out thing.p12
```

Problem is, openssl asks me for a password to encrypt the file. Is there a way to create an unencrypted PKCS#12 certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PKCS#12 appears to require private keys in the PKCS#12 container to be encrypted.

However, you can just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to use a blank password.

---

<sub>Note: PKCS#12 files are not certificates, only containers – they still have X.509 certificates inside.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The private key can be stored unencrypted by adding `-nodes`, but it will still ask for a password for the container file itself.  I haven't found a way to omit the container password when using OpenSSL.  One can give `-passout pass:` but I don't know whether this disables encryption or just encrypts with a zero-length key.  The tool always asks for a container key unless you specify one on the command line.